Randomly Ordering People Walking into a Room
This is a problem I thought of and am trying to figure out.

Suppose there are 100 people: Person1, Person2,... Person100.

A random person is selected and walks into the room.

The next person to walk into the room is randomly selected of the remaining group of people, based on the last person that walked into the room before them.

Individuals having a number closer to the person that just walked in are more likely to be selected. Individuals further away have less probability (the probability distribution does not need to be symmetric)


For example, if Person17 walked into the room, then Person18 and Person16 have higher probabilities of being selected next, whereas Person99 has a smaller probability of being selected next. This probability decreases the further you move away from the last person to walk into the room.
I am trying to create a discrete probability distribution to describe this problem.
Here is my idea so far:

Denote the set of all available numbers as $S$ and the last number as $L$.
Define the probability of drawing a number $x \in S$ (i.e., $x$ is in the set of available numbers) as follows:

$$ P(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{|x - L| + 1}}{\sum_{y \in S} \frac{1}{|y - L| + 1}} $$

Here, $|x - L|$ represents the absolute distance between $x$ and $L$.
A  1 is added to the denominator to avoid division by zero when $x = L$.

Now, I tried to make a test case.

Suppose I have numbers from 1 to 100.
The numbers 16, 54, 81, 82, 91 have been picked.
The last number was 54.
What is the probability of picking the number 17?

Here are the steps I used:
$$S = \{1, 2, ..., 15, 17, ..., 53, 55, ..., 80, 83, ..., 90, 92, ..., 100\}$$
$$ P(17) = \frac{\frac{1}{|17 - 54| + 1}}{\sum_{y \in S} \frac{1}{|y - 54| + 1}} $$
Have I done this problem correctly?
PS: Computer example and verification (in R)
calculate_probability <- function(S, L, x) {
  S <- S[S != L]
  

  if (!(x %in% S)) {
    return(0)
  }
 
  numerator <- 1 / (abs(x - L) + 1)

  denominator <- sum(1 / (abs(S - L) + 1))
  
  probability <- numerator / denominator
  
  return(probability)
}

# sanity check

S <- c(1:10)
L <- 8
x <- 8
probability <- calculate_probability(S, L, x)
print(probability) 

# probabilities sum to 1


S <- c(1:10)
L <- 8

S <- S[S != L]

probabilities <- sapply(S, function(x) calculate_probability(S, L, x))

print(probabilities)
sum(probabilities)


Your model makes sense. The +1 in the denominator isn't necessary since $L$ is excluded from $S$. In place of $1/(d+1)$, you could use any decreasing function that maps positive integers to non-negative real numbers.

thank you! I wrote a computer program to verify it as well
